# How can I remove the white bar in my header that appears in tablet view

Tags: css, wordpress, header, element

I recently redesigned the header of our website and now when minimizing it to tablet view there is a white bar showing in the header area that covers my header. the bar doesn't show up in the mobile or desktop version.  I tried looking it online and I couldn't find any solution that works with this issue. website is https://kamikazi.cc. [image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding in here:

```
 @media (max-width: 1024px)
    .elementor-98 .elementor-element.elementor-element-4a07762 {
        padding: 30px 20px 30px 20px;
    }
```

It'll work. 
Also, you have a bug in .elementor-row, try resizing your web and you'll see it, it should
be easy to fix.